# Mongoose Schemas Relationships

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two schemas first one is client which has client id and name:

Below is the schema code:

const ClientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

```
_id: Number,

org_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
},
```

});

Another schema is User which has Object id and username:

below is the schema code:

const User = mongoose.model('user', {

```
username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
},
```

});

Now, I want to add each and every user with clientschema id. How do I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

We can fix this by modifying clientSchema model to include a user with it’s type set to mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId like so.

user schema is:

```
username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
},
});
```

**modified clientSchema** :

```
  const ClientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    
    _id: Number,
    
    org_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
    },
    
        user:{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'user'},
    
    });
```

Saving user:

```
const user= new User({
       'myusername'
    });

const result = await user.save();
```

saving clientSchema:

```
const clientschema= new clientSchema({
        'myorg_name',
        user // user object
    });

const clientresult = await clientschema.save();
```

now check clientschema document in mongodb and you will see user object id with it.

refere below link

https://vegibit.com/mongoose-relationships-tutorial/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).